# Help installing Git

Tags: windows, git

I have read a turotial that is using git http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-version-control-with-git/ .  I then go to download what it says to [msysgit installer](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)" However there is no option to download this MSYSGIT but instead ONLY GitGUI.  How can I install Git from this package and access it from a command prompt?

Comment: add a [Windows] tag to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package 'Git-1.6.5.1-preview20091022.exe' is what you want. This is the msysgit Installer.

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange because I see a list of links that *has not* anything GitGUI related but has a [msysGit](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe) installator link.

Comment: That installer is only for people wishing to hack on Git itself. It is more complex and downloads more stuff. If you only plan to use Git as a tool, then get the other package

Comment: From this point of view http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.6.5.1-preview20100112-with-cheetah.exe is even better because it provides also Explorer integration without which it's hard to use any VCS under Windows, and Git version is same. Anyway, they both are marked as 'Featured Beta'.